# Counting down an array of integers using $timer in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, timer

I am currently learning how to use $timer in angularjs for some simple countdowns and was able to find plenty of resources that showed me how to do a basic countdown or count up timer such as the one located here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dpeaep/LQGE2/1/

However, I am trying to loop through an array of integers, counting down each one, one at a time, until they each hit 0.

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc11.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
        Counter: {{counter}} 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my js file:

```
function AlbumCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.counterArray = [5,10,15];
    $scope.onTimeout = function(){
      for(var i = 0; i < counterArray.length; i++){
        $scope.counterArray[i]--;
        if ($scope.counter > 0) {
            mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
        }
      }
    }
    var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);          
}
```

In this example I am trying to show a countdown from 5 to 0, then 10 to 0, and finally 15 to 0 in 1 second intervals. I modified the code in the above jsfiddle file and just added an int array and for loop, but nothing appears to be working.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/vaqene/1/edit

Any advice on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.. Works perfectly as you wanted..

```
  function AlbumCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
      $scope.counterArray = [5,10,15];
      $scope.counter = 5;

      $scope.index = 0;

      $scope.onTimeout = function() {
          $scope.counter = --$scope.counterArray[$scope.index];

          if ($scope.counterArray[$scope.index] === 0 && $scope.index < 3) {
              $scope.index++;         
          }

        $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);

      };



    $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

  }
```

Comment: how to do in vanillajs?